# how to use end='' outside of a print statement

Tags: python

```
for i in list(ident.split()):
    print(i.capitalize(), end='')
```

Is there a way to join all elements of i together. It seems to work fine with the end='' function while printing. Although, you are unable to do this outside of a print function.

```
for i in list(ident.split()):
    ident = (i.capitalize(), end='') #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you show what is your input and expected output?

Comment: Please reformulate your question, because right now it is totally unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: The `end` you're using is an argument to the `print` function. It's not obvious what you expect it to do in some other context.

Comment: you mean I guess ''.join(map(str.capitilize,ident.split()))? However, I think you just need ident.title() to capitalize every word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `end=''` is a keyword argument passed to the `print` function.
The `print` function will receive an argument named `end` whose value is equal to `''`.

On the other hand, `(i.capitalize(), end='')` raises a `SyntaxError`, because Python sees an assignation at a wrong place.

The `print` function will print in the console the first argument, and will the print the string passed as `end` keyword argument.
Therefore, when iterating over a list and printing the elements with `end='x'`, the output looks like a string of the elements of the list, separated with `'x'`.
However, no such string is actually built.

What you want is the `join` string method.
It should be called on the string used as separator, and its parameter should be an iterable of the strings to join.

Your printing loop is:

```
for i in list(ident.split()):
    print(i.capitalize(), end='')
```

The equivalent string will be created by:

```
s = ''.join(i.capitalize() for i in list(ident.split()))
```

If you're not familiar with generator expressions and comprehensions, this is equivalent to:

```
l = []
for i in list(ident.split()):
    l.append(i.capitalize())
s = ''.join(l)
```

By the way, `str.split` returns a list, so you don't need to convert it into a list. You should replace `list(ident.split())` by `ident.split()`.

Comment: @jamesjake You should just use `ident.title()` probably

Comment: @Chris_Rands In this specific case, I agree. I have to admit I did not know of the `title` method...